# Nuget: how can I tell which project is referencing a package?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

My project on UAT is throwing an exception concerning a NuGet package that exists on my dev environment (that is, I found under my /packages folder), but does not seems to be part of my solution (that is, I launch NuGet Package Manager but I cannot find it under the list of Installed packages).

The code runs fine on dev, but crashes on UAT.

My question is: how do I figure out where this library is being used?

Answer (score 1):

Some NuGet packages have trouble uninstalling completely, so there may still be leftover references in your project files (`.csproj`, `.vbproj`,...).

First, check for `<Reference Include="..">` elements containing a `<HintPath>` pointing to the missing folder. you should remove them.

Then check for `<Project Import="..." />` elements pointing to the missing folder. There may also be some conditions (for `<Error>` elements) checking if paths exists. Remove all of these.

Then delete your `packages` folder containing all the NuGet packages and re-open the solution in VS and restore the packages.

This can result in two outcomes:

1. It works and you successfully removed all "dangling" references to NuGet packages that are no longer in use.
2. You cannot compile because auf missing NuGet packages. In this case, install the NuGet packages again via the package management UI.